# Liferay portal theme issue

Tags: liferay, themes

occasionally when hitting the landing page after signing in, the users personal space is displayed instead of the default guest page. This is does not happen often, but my boss does not want it happening. I am hard pressed for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really programming related - the [liferay forums](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/forums) would help a lot better with that problem.

Other than that liferay tends to remember your last visited page - which bit me more than once when one part of the site was included in an iframe portlet - the iframe content was the remembered "last" visited page, not the one containing the iframe. After Login, that was the target.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the personal pages are shown after login if the desired landing page (or the last visited page) was not found.

You can disable the redirect to the last visited page after login by setting `auth.forward.by.last.path=false` in **portal-ext.properties**